# About subquery in MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

When I use MySQL, the following query runs clean.

```
SELECT 1 as num1, (select(num1 + 1)) as num2
```

But PostgreSQL is returning an error.

```
ERROR: column "num1" does not exist
```

Why is it responding differently?

Comment: What means `doesn't work`?

Comment: sorry, I mean the sql could't run in PostgreSQL

Comment: error is ```ERROR: column "num1" does not exist```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use PostgreSQL syntax , because PgSql does not support sub query this way, try this

```
WITH tblcontent AS (SELECT 1 as num1)
SELECT num1, num1 + 1 AS num2 from tblcontent
```

Answer (score 4):

The question shouldn't be why does Postgres not support this syntax, but why MySQL does. In most RDBMSs, aliases are only resolved after the query is executed, so you can't use them from within the query that declares them. E.g., the more common usecase - you cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause of the query/table-element that declared it.

One way around this is to use subqueries:

```
SELECT num1, num1 + 1 AS num2
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS num1) t
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow aliases in WHERE either.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any good source, but I am quite sure that the standard does not require aliases of projected columns to be visible inside a correlated sub query. I just tried it in SQL Server and Oracle, and both of them seem to agree with PostgreSQL here, rejecting using `x` in a correlated sub query, no matter in which clause of the outer select it is located.

It is similar to how MySQL allows the following query:

```sql
SELECT a + 1 x
FROM t
ORDER BY x + 1
```

but SQL Server and Postgres do not. MySQL seems to be more permissive with regard to using aliases in various clauses than the standard requires.

Comment: yeah; that's because select if evaluated after anything else. But why not allowing `select 1 as num1, num1+1 as num2`